# Performance & Diagnostics for Background Task

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I see how to use Debug->Performance and Diagnostics for the main UI project, but how can I use these tools for a background task?

Specifically I care about making sure my background task is staying within time/memory constraints when network could be poor.

Another idea, was to toast the memory usage from my bg task, but there isn't a way a background task can know the current memory usage b/c the MemoryManager class doesn't exist for Windows Runtime Components (which all bg tasks have to run as).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess at an answer is using the "Windows Phone Developer Power Tools(8.1)" included with the SDK.

You put a breakpoint on the first line of your background task code.  Then (since its running) use power tools to select performance monitor and then "BACKGROUNDTASKHOST" as the process.  For me ~2.2MB is used right away in the private bytes.  Put a breakpoint at the end of your background task and see how much it goes up.  After the bg task is done, then it will be gone from power tools.